# Why the servo keep shaking when I used PWM to control it on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, pwm

I am trying use GPIO to simulate pwm output to control a servo on my raspi B board. But the servo keep shaking and can't stop in a expect postion. Any one know the reason about that?

---

The source code may like below:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
vertical = GPIO.PWM(12, 50)
vertical.start(14)
time.sleep(0.2)
vertical.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
```

Comment: Please add more information on how you have the setup made. I used a servo on the pi and did not have such problem.

Comment: Try the raspberry pi stack exchange: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @0Ds0 The source code may like below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add a PCA9685 which is an I²C-bus controlled 16-channel PWM output between Raspi and servo. The servo can works correctly.
My guess is that Linux run on Raspi is not RTOS. So PWM output may not stable.